# Ninja Forms hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, ninja-forms

I am looking for an action hook that runs when a form is published. Reason being, is that I am trying to add a form key programmatically at the point of creation. I cannot find such a hook within the Ninja Forms documentation.

Does anybody know if such a hook exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else was stuck on this I found the answer. The action hook I required was 'ninja_forms_save_form'. This allows you to hook in functionality when a form is saved on the back end.